# Android camera takePicture failed after focus

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, autofocus

Following code uses to get jpeg-photo from camera

```
public void getPhoto(final PictureCallback callback, final Runnable focusFailCallback) {
    if(!Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED.equals(mCamera.getParameters().getFocusMode()) &&
            !Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY.equals(mCamera.getParameters().getFocusMode())) {
        mCamera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                if(success) {
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, null, callback);
                } else {
                    camera.cancelAutoFocus();
                    focusFailCallback.run();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, callback);
    }
}
```

Mostly it works fine. It calls between `startPreview` and `stopPreview` calls, so I have not problems about that. But at random moments it can throw exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1828)
org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$2.onAutoFocus(JavaCameraView.java:463)
android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1273)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5534)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
```

I have no idea what could happen that I didn't provide for.

Comment: This question has been asked before: *[takePicture failed after autofocus for the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098474/takepicture-failed-after-autofocus-for-the-second-time)* but I am not flagging it as duplicate because **a)** it is not clear if the issue only happens on second attempt to take picture, and **b)** it is not clear which of suggested answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17106168/192373), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24260832/192373) (if any) will help here.

Comment: @AlexCohn From this question I've allready got `cancelAutoFocus` method call. Mostly it helps. Code can work fine 2 times, 3, 5 and more. Also it can crash at 1st time. I don't know why it did so or why it not. Now I just placed `onAutoFocus` method body into `try-catch` block just to not crash my app, but I can't say it is correct.

Comment: auch. `try-catch` is not a nice solution, but with camera implementations coming from so many different vendors, these Runtime Exceptions do happen in most unexpected situations. *E.g.* when you demo your shiny app to an investor.

Comment: You only check that current camera focus mode is not fixed or infinity. But probably you should set it explicitly to [FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)? Also, read the explanations there, the instructions when you can/should cancel autoFocus.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a Moto E3 and some other devices and calling `cancelAutoFocus` right before `camera.takePicture` made the crash disappear.

Comment: This may be throwing the baby with the water: [*... this function will return the focus position to the default.*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#cancelAutoFocus()). It isn't explicitly stated there, but there is no contract that camera will still be focused for **takePicture()**.

Comment: I haven't checked the native source code behind this method, but from my experience with this method on several devices, the focus is not changed after calling it.

Comment: the native code behind this method isn't very relevant, because it only [goes all the way](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/qcom/camera/+/547442802b5d87d8067d02d736cda174efff9d5d/QCamera2/HAL/QCamera2HWI.cpp#2501) to Camera HW driver and God knows how each ISP implements this operation.